# Error: Django settings "The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty."

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having a problem that has been asked before but I think this case is special. The problem comes because it does not find the "SECRET_KEY" but as I will show you below, it is set.

To better understand my settings configuration, they are divided in the following files: **settings/base.py**, **settings/dev.py** and **settings/prod.py**. From the base.py file is where the other settings import their configurations. Next I will leave you all the configurations.

**base.py**

```
"""
Django settings for portfolio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'blablabla'

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'weatherapi',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'core',
    'blog',
    'weather',
    'bootstrap4',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'django_bootstrap_icons',
    'chartjs',
    'ckeditor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ES'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Establece los permisos por defecto de la api,si el usuario no tiene permisos solo puede leer
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
  ],
}

SITE_ID = 1

# No enviar emails de verificacion
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
# Cambiar el authentication user Email en vez de Name
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True

# La autenticacion con tokens
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

# NOTES TO CUSTOMIZE CKEDITOR
# This setting show all editor tools in admin panel
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    }
}
```

**dev.py**

```
from portfolio.settings.base import *
DEBUG = True

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(
    'SECRET_KEY',
    'blabladev'
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'portfolio',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**prod.py**

```
from portfolio.settings.base import *
DEBUG = False
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(
    'SECRET_KEY',
    'blablaprod'
)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'devcode.la',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', ''),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', ''),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', ''),
    }
}
```

As a fact, the project is executed perfectly by the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=portfolio.settings.dev
```

But it is giving me the error when running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**Error:**

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: You say you run `python manage.py makemigrations`? Specify the settings there too (`--settings=portfolio.settings.dev`), does your `settings` directory have a `__init__.py` and does this declare any settings (Or just use a wildcard import)?

Comment: Add a `___init___.py` empty file to the `settings`  directory and try import with `from .base import *`

Comment: Sorry for not specifying it, but my /settings does contain an __init__.py file. @AbdulAzizBarkat Exactly Thanks! that is the problem, if I use "--settings=portfolio.settings.dev" it works!. Why can't I use it without specifying the settings file?